# Determine the decimal precision of an input number

Tags: c#, decimal, precision, decimal-point

We have an interesting problem were we need to determine the decimal precision of a users input (textbox). Essentially we need to know the number of decimal places entered and then return a precision number, this is best illustrated with examples:

4500 entered will yield a result 1
4500.1 entered will yield a result 0.1
4500.00 entered will yield a result 0.01
4500.450 entered will yield a result 0.001

We are thinking to work with the string, finding the decimal separator and then calculating the result. Just wondering if there is an easier solution to this.

Comment: Are you sure 4500 would be a 1, and not a 100?

Comment: What is expected result in case 0.0 and 0.1 ?

Comment: For Me it is confusing question. You do not ask for decimal precision. You ask: how to get the number of digits in a fraction part. Definition for 'decimal precision' is here for Me: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209

Answer (score 21):

I think you should just do what you suggested - use the position of the decimal point. Obvious drawback might be that you have to think about internationalization yourself.

```
var decimalSeparator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

var position = input.IndexOf(decimalSeparator);

var precision = (position == -1) ? 0 : input.Length - position - 1;

// This may be quite unprecise.
var result = Math.Pow(0.1, precision);
```

There is another thing you could try - the `Decimal` type stores an internal precision value. Therefore you could use `Decimal.TryParse()` and inspect the returned value. Maybe the parsing algorithm maintains the precision of the input.

Finally I would suggest not to try something using floating point numbers. Just parsing the input will remove any information about trailing zeros. So you have to add an artifical non-zero digit to preserve them or do similar tricks. You might run into precision issues. Finally finding the precision based on a floating point number is not simple, too. I see some ugly math or a loop multiplying with ten every iteration until there is no longer any fractional part. And the loop comes with new precision issues...

**UPDATE**

Parsing into a decimal works. Se [`Decimal.GetBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) for details.

```
var input = "123.4560";

var number = Decimal.Parse(input);

// Will be 4.
var precision = (Decimal.GetBits(number)[3] >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
```

From here using `Math.Pow(0.1, precision)` is straight forward.

**UPDATE 2**

Using decimal.GetBits() will allocate an `int[]` array. If you want to avoid the allocation you can use the following helper method which uses an explicit layout struct to get the scale directly out of the decimal value:

```
static int GetScale(decimal d)
{
    return new DecimalScale(d).Scale;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct DecimalScale
{
    public DecimalScale(decimal value)
    {
        this = default;
        this.d = value;
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    decimal d;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    int flags;

    public int Scale => (flags >> 16) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: +1 For decimal.Precision, I had no idea it could do this :) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132765/adjusting-decimal-precision-net

Comment: Since the OP asked for "an easier solution", and perhaps inferred "better performing", how does this compare performance-wise to just parsing the string?

Comment: You have in the comment, "will be 4", but the precision of "123.4560" should be 7.  The scale should be 4.

Comment: Is there anyway for 123.4560 to get precision=3? since 0 at the end should not count?

Comment: can someone please explain why there is  "& 0x000000FF" at the end of first update?

Comment: In .NET7 decimal got a [`Scale` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.scale?view=net-7.0), so your code can be simplyfied to: `Math.Pow(0.1, value.Scale);` and likewise your `GetScale` wouldn't be needed anymore.

Answer (score 11):

> Just wondering if there is an easier
>   solution to this.

No.

Use string:

```
string[] res = inputstring.Split('.');
int precision = res[1].Length;
```

Comment: The character to split on needs to be the correct decimal separator - [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Since your last examples indicate that trailing zeroes are significant, I would rule out any numerical solution and go for the string operations.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no easier solution, you have to examine the string. If you convert `"4500"` and `"4500.00"` to numbers, they both become the value `4500` so you can't tell how many non-value digits there were behind the decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

As an interesting aside, the `Decimal` tries to maintain the precision entered by the user.  For example,

```
Console.WriteLine(5.0m);
Console.WriteLine(5.00m);
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Parse("5.0"));
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Parse("5.00"));
```

Has output of:

```
5.0
5.00
5.0
5.00
```

If your motivation in tracking the precision of the input is purely for input and output reasons, this may be sufficient to address your problem.

Comment: See Daniel Bruckner's answer for how to access this information directly.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the string is easy enough.

If there is no "." in the string, return 1.

Else return "0.", followed by n-1 "0", followed by one "1", where n is the length of the string after the decimal point.

Comment: Warning: First make sure the string is a valid number/the last character isn't a "."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution using strings;

```
static double GetPrecision(string s)
{ 
    string[] splitNumber = s.Split('.');
    if (splitNumber.Length > 1)
    {
        return 1 / Math.Pow(10, splitNumber[1].Length);
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

There is a question here; [Calculate System.Decimal Precision and Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763942/calculate-system-decimal-precision-and-scale) which looks like it might be of interest if you wish to delve into this some more.

Comment: You need to use [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) to get the correct decimal separator for the locale.