# Format decimal number with set maximal precision but without unneeded trailing zeroes

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, decimal

I Have used following code to format decimals

```
return string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO"), "{0:N3}", decVal);
```

If the decVal do not contain decimals I do not want to show decimal points but I want to show the figure with the correct formatting without zero s , How to perform this ?

Comment: Can you please show an example for input and expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer

Comment: @UweKeim That question is actually a bit different (although the correct answer to this one is buried there as well).

Comment: @SonerGönül 74,200 with decimals and without 56,000 <= this should display as 56 , Thank you

Comment: @UweKeim Ah, ok, so with this comment it's obvious that you were entirely right on the duplicate question, even though the OP has written it wrong :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use custom numeric format like:

```
return string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO"), "{0:0.###}", decVal);
```

You may want to read about [standard numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) and [custom numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:**

To handle the thousands separators you could use:

```
return string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO"), "{0:#,0.###}", decVal);
```

But, to handle some specific cases you'd better to implement formats like it is described in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415405/decimal-to-string-with-thousands-separators).

**P.S.:** Thanks @Luaan for the (0.###);

Comment: I'd use `0.###` instead. You usually don't want to hide a zero :)

Comment: @Luaan I need to use the comma as the decimal seperator

Comment: @Kirov `.` in a format specifier is the decimal separator (`,` being the thousands separator). Use the proper culture and it will be written as a comma on output.