# Easy way to parse decimal to string with Thousand's Separator

Tags: c#, winforms

Easy way to parse decimal to string with thousand's separator.

for Example :

i fetch a decimal from Database was `100000000.00` with field's type `decimal(18,2)` and i have a `TextBox` in my Form with name's `"payTxt"`.

then

i want parse `100000000.00` to `100.000.000,00` for fill the `"payTxt"`.

i don't know why every i set `"payTxt.Text = "100000000.00" "`

its become `"100000000,00"`

Comment: `CultureInfo.NumberFormat` it has something to do with this

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415405/decimal-to-string-with-thousands-separators

Comment: parsing would be turning a string into a decimal, this sounds like you want **formatting**

Comment: While I think it's better to use NumericUpDown for data entry, another thing you should know is that String.Format() and ToString() method works based on Culture, You can take a look at examples that I provided. You should know `ToString("N2")` may result in a string that you don't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use a `NumericUpDown` control with `ThousandSeparator` set to true and `DecimalPlaces` set to 2, and `Maximum` set to the value that you need:

here is result of setting the value: 1234567.89

[image]

This way:

- Thousand separator and decimal point will be shown even when data entry.
- You can set minimum and maximum allowed values
- The user can only enter valid number values
- You can set the increment when user clicks on arrows or use arrow keys.

Another thing you should know is that String.Format() and ToString() method works based on Culture, for example:

```
//Shows value based on your Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:N2}", 123456.78));

//Shows 123,456.78
MessageBox.Show(String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"), "{0:N2}", 123456.78));

//Shows 123,456/78
MessageBox.Show(String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa"), "{0:N2}", 123456.78));

//Shows result based on your Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
MessageBox.Show((123456.78).ToString("N2"));

//Shows 123,456.78
MessageBox.Show((123456.78).ToString("N2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")));

//Shows 123,456/78
MessageBox.Show((123456.78).ToString("N2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
payTxt.Text = YourVariable.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: You should add some explanation for your answer.

Comment: LOL... This post is 4 years old.

Answer (score 0):

to get 100.000.000,00 try the following:

```
Decimal dec = 100000000.00M;
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("el-GR"); 
payTxt.Text = dec.ToString("0,0.00", ci);
```

for more info look on the following link:
[Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8)

"el-GR" is actually the greek CultureInfo, most other cultures will show a comma for the thousand digit separators.