# Legacy code is formatting a number. How can I express this in a more modern / understood way?

Tags: c#

Just bumped into this line of code:

```
string sNumFormat = new string('0', Convert.ToString(totalCount).Length);
```

where totalCount is an integer.

It's used here:

```
kNewComp.Name
    = baseName + string.Format("{0:" + sNumFormat + "}", 1 + componentIndex);
```

I'm pretty sure this is just an interesting way of ensuring numbers are padded with leading zeroes, but I haven't seen it expressed quite like this before.

Is there a more standard way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: As your code already works, this would fit better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, take a look at [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewComp.Name = baseName + string.Format("{0:" + sNumFormat + "}", 1 + componentIndex);
```

Can be replaced with

```
var s = (1 + componentIndex).ToString();
var digits = (int) (Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(totalCount)));
Console.Write(s.PadLeft(digits, '0'));
```

And then you can get rid of `sNumFormat`.

Note that converting to `string` is not a good way to measure digits. See: [Get number of digits before decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546793/get-number-of-digits-before-decimal-point)