# How can I validate that a value passed to a SqlParameter will not fail precision and Scale?

Tags: c#, validation, scale, precision, sqlparameter

How can I validate that a value passed to a SqlParameter will not fail the **Precision** and **Scale** properties **at the time of setting** the value, rather than waiting for the "System.ArgumentException" to be thrown when **ExecuteReader** is called on my command object, so I can throw an **ArgumentoutOfRange** exception earlier in my code and fail fast?

**Example**

```
        Decimal myValue = 123456789.234M;

        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("MyParameter", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        parameter.Precision = 10;
        parameter.Scale = 2;
        /* I'd like to fail here at the line below as the value does not conform to precision and scale */
        parameter.Value = myValue;
```

Comment: Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: Could you make an extension method to validate the value?

Comment: Are you asking how to [Calculate System.Decimal Precision and Scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763942/calculate-system-decimal-precision-and-scale)?

Comment: @corak - yes that may be a better way of putting it. I'll read your link

Comment: @Corak - Just to confirm your link sent me in the right direction.