# floating point number

Tags: c#, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extracting mantissa and exponent from double in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c)

How do you separate the fraction and the exponent in a floating point number?

In C++, I was able to use a **"union"**,  but unions are not allowed in C#.

```
union  {fix lc; long double cv;} ldblun;
```

Comment: That doesn't work in C++ either.

Comment: What you need the fraction for? Maybe we can solve this by further investigating your problem. There are dozens of possibilities to get what you want however.

Answer (score 1):

`BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits()`

Then just shift and mask.

Comment: sorry i misinterpreted the question .. thanks for pointing it out