# Getting significand and exponent value from floating point literal with C#

Tags: c#, floating-point

A literal of 0.25 can be expressed with 1*2^(-2) so that we can get 1 as significand and -2 as exponent.

What function can I get the significand/exponent with C#?

```
int significand = GetSignificand(0.25); // 1 
int exponent = GetExponent(0.25); // -2
```

As the floating point numbers are stored in sign/significand/exponent format, I think there should be a straightforward way to read them.

Comment: Why is it 1*2^(-2) ? Why not 2^-4*4 ?

Comment: you'd better write 4*2^(-4)... what you write is bit different. and to your question, I think, he would something like a * 2 ^ b where a and b are to found...

Comment: sasjaq, that's my point, based on what rules do you further restrict the infinite number of combinations of a and b that satisfy the outlined condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting mantissa and exponent from double in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c-sharp)