# VB.net Math.Round rounding issue - different results for same input

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

We're running into an issue with VB.NET's `Math.Round` method where we're getting different results for the same input. The problem is reproducible and best illustrated using this short piece of code containing a simple moving average function:

```
Public Class bug

 Public Shared Function ExponentialMovingAverage(Values() As Double) As Double
   Dim Weight, TotalWeight As Double
   ExponentialMovingAverage = 0
   Weight = 1
   TotalWeight = 0
   For Each Value In Values
    ExponentialMovingAverage += Value*Weight
    TotalWeight += Weight
    Weight /= 1-2/(Values.Length+1)
   Next
   ExponentialMovingAverage /= TotalWeight
   Return ExponentialMovingAverage
 End Function

 Public Shared Sub Main
   Dim v As Double = 20.41985000000000000000
   Console.WriteLine( _
    ExponentialMovingAverage({77.474, 1.4018}).ToString("0.00000000000000000000") & " --> " & _
    Math.Round(ExponentialMovingAverage({77.474, 1.4018}), 4) & vbCrLf & _
    v.ToString("0.00000000000000000000") & " --> " & _
    Math.Round(v, 4))
 End Sub

End Class
```

Running this code gives the following output (culture *nl-NL*):

```
20,41985000000000000000 --> 20,4199
20,41985000000000000000 --> 20,4198
```

We're wondering why the output is different for 2 seemingly identical calls to `Math.Round`. There should not be any precision problems as the value used has less digits than the [15-16 digits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(VS.71).aspx) that should fit in a `Double` data type.

Searching the web mainly returns answers to rounding problems having to do with `MidpointRounding`, which seems unrelated.

Looking forward to any replies.

Comment: When I test the above your function `ExponentialMovingAverage` produces an output of 20.419850000000004

Comment: You *don't* have different results from the same input. `Math.Round()` is deterministic. You have different results from inputs which *look* the same. The underlying floats are in base 2. An artifact of displaying base 2 numbers in base 10 is that occasionally different numbers display the same. It seems that VB.net unfortunately lacks a built-in `frexp()` which lets you easily inspect the  underlying bit-patterns, but something like this should be easy to translate to vb if you are curious: http://stackoverflow.com/q/389993/4996248

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because, by default, Math.Round is using `ToEven` as its rounding approach.  If you switch to this:

```
    Console.WriteLine( _
        ExponentialMovingAverage({77.474, 1.4018}).ToString("0.00000000000000000000") & " --> " & _
        Math.Round(ExponentialMovingAverage({77.474, 1.4018}), 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) & vbCrLf & _
        v.ToString("0.00000000000000000000") & " --> " & _
        Math.Round(v, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
```

then the result is as you expect.  Your hard coded value is exactly 20.41985 so `ToEven` will turn it into 20.4198.  I suspect your calculated result is very fractionally larger than 20.41985 (as stated above I also get 20.419850000000004 as the result) and so is rounded up.

Ref [MidPointRounding docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx)