# Extracting floating-point significand and exponent in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, exponent, significant-digits

I would like to be able to extract the significand and exponent of floating-point numbers in NumPy. Getting the exponent as an integer is fine and ok for the significand. Getting the significand as a bitfield would be even more convienient.

I am aware that Python floats have a `hex` method; however, I wish to use `numpy.float32`, numpy arrays, and ufuncs. I am also aware of the numpy `view` method that allows me to see the float as an integer and thus as a binary string:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> b = bin(np.float32(1.23456789).view(np.int32))
'0b111111100111100000011001010010'

>>> b[-23:] # extract last 23 bits of IEEE 754 binary32 float, is significand
'00111100000011001010010'
```

Extracting the exponent and sign in this way is not convenient, as leading 0s are dropped by `bin`. (I could left-pad to 32 bits with 0s though…)

In any case, because `bin` is not a ufunc, this is not convenient and I would have to iterate over the array.

Isn't there any more convenient approach to doing what I want?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16444786/3214872), it might point you in the riht direction

Comment: @GPhilo: Thanks. Actually, that answer seems to make it clear that, no, there is no more convenient approach.

Comment: Take a look at [`numpy.frexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frexp.html)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: `numpy.frexp` gives *a* decomposition into exponent and *mantissa*, not *the* decomposition into exponent and *significand* encoded in an IEEE 754 float. (The exponent given by `frexp` differs by one from the IEEE 754 float exponent.)

Comment: @equaeghe: Yes, but it's trivial to get from the `frexp` result to the IEEE 754 decomposition. As you say, the exponent differs by one, so subtract one from the exponent and double the significand.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: True, but I'd still need to extract the significand separately. I don't see how I could do all the steps any shorter than in my self-answer. Perhaps you can add an answer for me to up-vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPhilio's comment triggered a more thorough search on SO which resulted in the following solution, based on [an answer to “extracting mantissa and exponent from double in c#”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390072):

```
import numpy as np

def decompose(x: np.float32): 
    """decomposes a float32 into negative, exponent, and significand"""
    negative = x < 0
    n = np.abs(x).view(np.int32) # discard sign (MSB now 0),
                                 # view bit string as int32
    exponent = (n >> 23) - 127 # drop significand, correct exponent offset
                               # 23 and 127 are specific to float32
    significand = n & np.int32(2**23 - 1) # second factor provides mask
                                          # to extract significand
    return (negative, exponent, significand)
```

This approach with bit-level operations of integers is actually more convenient that going to the actual bitstring itself.